# What exactly does the ding-dong theory of the origin of language state, according to Max Müller?

Tags: reference-request, origin-of-language, sound-symbolism, history-of-linguistics

Max Müller is mentioned as one of the pioneers of the study of the origins of language, as he [created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_language) a typology for the earlier origin of language theories based on the channel they draw the connection between sounds and meanings upon.

The ding-dong theories were supposed to see the connection in some kind of "natural resonance". I don't think Müller refers to actual sound resonance. In his work, he doesn't mention much more than Wikipedia: "*Müller suggested what he called the ding-dong theory, which states that all things have a vibrating natural resonance, echoed somehow by man in his earliest words*." This "natural resonance"

Did he meant something along the lines of: "There IS some kind of mysterious connection but we don't know what's behind it."? Or does the "natural resonance" actually refer to the "concept of the word" - (for ex. "[kiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect)" is made of short and intermittent sounds)?

EDIT: No longer valid source switched for Wikipedia.

Comment: "Ny inlaga" simply means "new attachment". The directory `http://www.ling.gu.se/~abelin/` no longer seems to exist, so this seems to have been a very temporary and unofficial publication.  There is a person with the same last name at GU who is a professor of linguistics so this seems like more than just a conincidence (it's not a very common last name in Sweden). The publications link on her staff page is a Microsoft Word file but if your pain threhold is higher than mine, perhaps there is an official publication there which this was a draft of.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_language says *"Müller suggested what he called the* ding-dong *theory, which states that all things have a vibrating natural resonance, echoed somehow by man in his earliest words"* and contrasts this against imitation or onomatopoetic hypotheses. Sounds (sic) to me like this really is about acoustic resonance.

Comment: For context, perhaps see also https://orgtheory.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/origins-of-language-ding-dong-bow-wow-pooh-pooh/

Comment: "resonance", even if limited to accoustics, has more than one dimension. So this could go a long way. Linus Akkenson described the recursiveness of music thus: there's tone, rhythm, arrengement, which all fall in the same regime of time. But arrangement obviously has depth. So, on the one hand, "wood" might sound like wood, whereas "tree" is a little more complex; of course that's subject to sound shift, and G *Baum*, or PIE \*doru "tree" are different, whereas we are interested in much earlier utterance. On the other hand, dialog is a form of call and request. So I have to echo your question!